# Restrict access to admin buttons on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, admin

I have the following code to some buttons and I want normal users just to be able to click on the "read" button

```
<?php
    include 'database.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td>'. $row['email'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td>'. $row['mobile'] . '</td>';

      echo '<td>'. $row['user_type'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td width=250>';
      echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
      echo ' ';
      echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
      echo ' ';
      echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
      echo '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    Database::disconnect();
?>
```

I have 2 fields on MySQL DB (user_type (enum) and userRoleID(int))
I've tried some codes but i delete it unfortunaly, so I would like to know if anyone could give me some example of what do to to restrict normal users to access that buttons.. Please help, I'm working on it about 1/2 weeks and I can figure how to do it even after search a lot..Thanks!

Comment: Compare current user data with something and decide - output buttons or not.

Comment: Don't forget to perform this same authorization check on `update.php` and `delete.php` as well.  Just because you don't show someone a link doesn't mean they can never perform that request.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the button inside `if()` statement according to user role or type

`if($row['user_type'] == 'normal user') { ......}`

Use some conditional caluse like `!=` or `==`  to match your need

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if($row['user_type']!="normaluser")
{
  echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
  echo ' ';
  echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
}
```

Comment: It worked somehow.. but maybe i express myself worng.. it just hide the buttons on the table, and i want the user_type just to read if it is a normal user but when he log in on login.php page

Comment: you need to set user type in session variable after login 
$_SESSION['user_type'] 
check as per above logic

Comment: Can you show me some example of how to do that please? I'm kind of new with PHP but i really need to get this done ASAP :/
I have the login.php page and a server.php(another DB connection just for login) page on other folder.. maybe it isnt a good idea too.. but where should I use the session and how? :/